# Cant read cakephp session unless I write in the same controller

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I cant read my session data unless I write at the start of the controller I want to read from.
Example below:

```
public function login(){
$this->Session->write('Facebook.accessToken','This now works superb');
    //TODO: Implement check to see if logged in user has the same session user id.
    require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS .'facebook.php');
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'REMOVED',
    'secret' => 'REMOVED'
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>'http://www.facebook.com/REMOVED'));
        $this->set('loginUrl',$loginUrl);
    }

    if(!isset($loginUrl)){
    // means that we are authenticated, so check for login with user id. If logged in redirect to event-list. If login failed display join form.    
        if($user = $this->User->findById($user_profile['id'])){
            if($this->Auth->login($user['User'])){
                $this->redirect('/users/dash');
            }
        }else{
            $this->Session->write('Facebook.accessToken2',$facebook->getAccessToken());
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'add'));
            }
    }
}


public function add(){
    debug($this->Session->read());
    $this->Session->write('testing','value');
    debug($this->Session->read());
    }
```

If I remove `$this->Session->write('Facebook.accessToken','This now works superb');` the controller will not write Facebook.accessToken2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Session component in your controller?

```
    $components[] = 'Session';
    //or
    public $components = array('Session');
```

Also, is this only in the login actionof this authentication controller or also in other controllers?

Comment: Yep, its in my `AppController`. This is my only login action (and currently the only controller).

Comment: I should have a look at the add() action? Since you are trying to read it BEFORE the write, it's obvious it's an unknown variable in that state. Also, $this->Session->read() needs a name of the variable you are trying to read. Have look at the cookbook would ya.

Comment: `$this->Session->read()` - "Returns the value at $name in the Session. If $name is null the entire session will be returned. " `login `redirects to `add` therefore I'm trying to read the data that was set in `login` then read it again after adding new data to it. Add is also included in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppController:

```
public $components = array('Session');
function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Session->write('Facebook.accessToken','This now works superb');
}
```

In your local controllers:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest stepping through the code with a debugger and XDebug enabled, to make sure the code paths that you're expecting are being followed.

Netbeans and Eclipse can do this for you, or any other php editor/ide with debbuging step-through capabilities.